# Rails - custom exceptions (errors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I'm trying to build my own `Exception` for tagged logging:

```
module Exceptions
  class GeneralException < StandardError
    LOGGER_NAME = 'Base'

    def initialize(message)
      @logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
      @logger.tagged(get_logger_name) { @logger.error message }
      @message = message
    end

    def get_logger_name
      self.class::LOGGER_NAME
    end
  end

  class InvalidDataException < GeneralException; end

  class SecurityException < GeneralException
    LOGGER_NAME = 'Security'
  end

  class ElasticSearchException < GeneralException
    LOGGER_NAME = 'Elastic'
  end
end
```

I'm expecting to be able to call this new exception with:

`raise Exceptions::SecurityException "Something security related happened.`

The problem is that when I call this I get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'SecurityException' for Exceptions:Module

Any idea how to correctly raise this error?

Comment: SecurityException isn't a method. It's a class. You need to instantiate it first, pass in the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, quite easy, you need to raise the instance of the error:

```
 raise Exceptions::SecurityException.new "Something security related happend."
```

or

```
 raise Exceptions::SecurityException, "Something security related happend."
```